# Global If Else Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://liveweave.com/EvfTww

I have two radio buttons one says div, and another says remove.
I add in some divs in html and when I select remove I want to be able to remove divs inside of #canvas when clicked.

The function provided below only works when divs are already visible when checked, but when I add new divs in the canvas from the code editor I also want to be able to remove those as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<table id="main" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="canvas" valign="top"></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id="control_box">
                <form id='tools'>
                    <input name="tool" id="tool-1" checked="checked" type="radio">
                    <label for="tool-1">DIV</label>

                    <input name="tool" id="tool-2" type="radio">
                    <label for="tool-2">Remove</label>
                </form><br>

                Border Width <select id="divborder">
                      <option value="1px">1px</option>
                      <option value="2px">2px</option>
                      <option value="3px" selected="selected">3px</option>
                      <option value="5px">5px</option>
                      <option value="7px">7px</option>
                      <option value="8px">8px</option>
                      <option value="9px">9px</option>
                      <option value="10px">10px</option>
                </select><br>

                Border Style <select id="divborderstyle">
                      <option value="dotted">dotted</option>
                      <option value="dashed">dashed</option>
                      <option value="solid" selected="selected">solid</option>
                      <option value="double">double</option>
                      <option value="groove">groove</option>
                      <option value="ridge">ridge</option>
                      <option value="inset">inset</option>
                      <option value="outset">outset</option>
                </select><br>

                Border Color 
                <input id="bcolor" type="text" name="bcolor" value="#f00" /></div><br>

                BG Color
                <input id="bgcolor" type="text" name="bgcolor" value="#000" onchange="window.set_fill_color(this.value); var col = this.value ; $('#colorSelectorFill').ColorPickerSetColor(col);" /></div>
                <input type="button" id="nobg" value="none">
            </div><br><br>

            <textarea id='code' placeholder="The #canvas acts as page body"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery/JavaScript**

```
$('#tool-2').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('Remove Tool Chosen! You can now remove divs within the canvas.');

        $('#canvas div').on('click', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            code.val(preview.html());
        });

    } else {
        alert('Houston we have a problem!');
    }
});
```

Comment: For starters, you need to change `$(this).on('checked')` to `$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: I think `on('checked')` should be `is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://liveweave.com/lXdfqr

Using basically the same function as before, but this time I put it in another function called canvastools, and I removed the else statement as I do not need that for this experiment.

```
function canvastools(e) {
    if ($('#tool-2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#canvas div').on('click', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            code.val(preview.html());
        });

    }
}
```

I then call the function by stating that when the document is changed it will call the function.

```
$(document).change(function(e) { 
    canvastools(e);
});
```

I found that using the select element is a bit easier, however it's not exactly isolated. The remove tool's function will still apply even when a another tool/option is selected. I haven't figured out how to fix that problem just yet.

Here's the new fiddle/weave - http://liveweave.com/e5Efnc

```
function wrappertools(e) {

    // Tools
    $("select#tools").each(function() {

        // DIV Tool
        if ($(this).val() === 'div') {
            $('#divoptions').show();
            $('#spanoptions').hide();

            // No Background Option
            $('#nobg').click(function() {
                $('input[name=bgcolor]').val('none');
            });

            var bcolor = $('input[name=bcolor]').val(),
                bgcolor = $('input[name=bgcolor]').val(),
                divborderstyle = $('#divborderstyle').val(),
                divborder = $('#divborder').val();

            alert('DIV Tool Selected!');
        }

        // Text Tool
        if ($(this).val() === 'text'){
            $('#spanoptions').show();
            $('#divoptions').hide();

          alert('Text Tool Selected!');

            // No Background Option
            $('#nospanbg').click(function() {
                $('input[name=spanbgcolor]').val('none');
            });

            $('#addspantext').on('click', function() {
                var spanbcolor = $('input[name=spanbcolor]').val(),
                    spanbgcolor = $('input[name=spanbgcolor]').val(),
                    spanborderstyle = $('#spanborderstyle').val(),
                    spanborder = $('#spanborder').val(),
                    spanfont = $('#spanfont').val(),
                    spancolor = $('#spancolor').val(),
                    spansize = $('#spansize').val(),
                    spantext = $('#spantext').val(),
                    placespan = $('<span style="position: relative; font-family: ' + spanfont + '; font-size: ' + spansize + '; font-color: ' + spancolor + '; border: ' + spanborder + ' ' + spanborderstyle + ' ' + spanbcolor + '; background: '+ spanbgcolor +';">' + spantext + '</span>');

                $('.wrapper').append(placespan);
                code.val(preview.html());
            });
            return false;
        }

        // Remove Tool
        if ($(this).val() === 'remove') {
          alert('Remove Tool Selected!');
            $('#divoptions').hide();
            $('#spanoptions').hide();
            $('.wrapper div, .wrapper span').on('click', function() {
                $(this).remove();
                code.val(preview.html());
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    wrappertools(e);
});

$(document).change(function(e) { 
    wrappertools(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="div" checked> div
<input type="radio" name="test" value="remove"> remove

$("input[@name='test']").change(function(){
    $("#parent_div_id").hide();
});
```